# TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple) , when calling next( iter( ) )

Tags: python, pytorch, typeerror

I was trying to load some data using pytorch, the code is like the followings:

```
test_ds = ImageFolder(root="./test", transform=data_transform)

test_dl = DataLoader(test_ds,batch_size=12)

x , y= next(iter(test_dl))
```

when `next(iter(test_dl))` is called, it throws `TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)` , I could not figure out why, since earlier when I did the same task using MAC, the result is OK, does this has something to do with OS

The full traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-cecf634332ce> in <module>
----> 1 next(iter(test_dl))

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    312         if self.num_workers == 0:  # same-process loading
    313             indices = next(self.sample_iter)  # may raise StopIteration
--> 314             batch = self.collate_fn([self.dataset[i] for i in indices])
    315             if self.pin_memory:
    316                 batch = pin_memory_batch(batch)

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    312         if self.num_workers == 0:  # same-process loading
    313             indices = next(self.sample_iter)  # may raise StopIteration
--> 314             batch = self.collate_fn([self.dataset[i] for i in indices])
    315             if self.pin_memory:
    316                 batch = pin_memory_batch(batch)

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py in __getitem__(self, index)
    101         sample = self.loader(path)
    102         if self.transform is not None:
--> 103             sample = self.transform(sample)
    104         if self.target_transform is not None:
    105             target = self.target_transform(target)

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py in __call__(self, img)
     47     def __call__(self, img):
     48         for t in self.transforms:
---> 49             img = t(img)
     50         return img
     51 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py in __call__(self, img)
    544         """
    545         i, j, h, w = self.get_params(img, self.scale, self.ratio)
--> 546         return F.resized_crop(img, i, j, h, w, self.size, self.interpolation)
    547 
    548     def __repr__(self):

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py in resized_crop(img, i, j, h, w, size, interpolation)
    329     assert _is_pil_image(img), 'img should be PIL Image'
    330     img = crop(img, i, j, h, w)
--> 331     img = resize(img, size, interpolation)
    332     return img
    333 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py in resize(img, size, interpolation)
    204             return img.resize((ow, oh), interpolation)
    205     else:
--> 206         return img.resize(size[::-1], interpolation)
    207 
    208 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in resize(self, size, resample, box)
   1890         self.load()
   1891 
-> 1892         return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
   1893 
   1894     def rotate(

TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Comment: You need to first assign it to a variable `it = iter(test_dl)` and then call `next(it)`

Comment: @PooyaKamranjam that makes no difference whatsoever

Comment: @PooyaKamranjam: That is false.  Something like `x = next(iter([1, 2, 3]))` works just fine.

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question. The bare error message is not enough.

Comment: the full traceback has been added to the question@StevenRumbalski

Comment: What is the structure of the data? Also, what does `DataLoader()` returns?

Comment: the `DataLoader( )` is imported from `torch.utils.data`, the result of `DataLoader()` will be passed into the CNN model for each epoch of training process